# Angular: Trying to disable button after amount of clicks

Tags: angular

I have a simple app that contains 3 things:

1. I have a random number between 1 and 20 that is displayed indefinitely (interval)
2. 2 up and down buttons that allow me to update the number after each advanced click on +1 or -1
3. A function (that does not work) that should disable the button after 20 clicks
   **(With the breakDown function)**

**Some of the functions I used in the service and it's important that it stays there**

**It is important to note that I only need help in the third part (the first 2 parts work for me)**

My [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9u7dpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Felevator.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) :

My Service:

```
export class ElevatorService {

  floor = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
  floorNumber: number = -1;
  Count = 0;


  constructor() {
  }

  getRandomNumbers() {
    return interval(1000)
    .pipe(
      map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1),
      tap(res => this.floorNumber = res));
  }

  breakDown(){
    this.Count++;
    if(this.Count >= 20)
    return false;
    return true;
}
```

My component.ts:

```
 export class AppComponent {
  floor = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
  Count = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Count++;
    this.elevatorService.getRandomNumbers().subscribe(this.floor);
  }

  constructor(private elevatorService: ElevatorService) {}

  breakDown() {
    const breakDown = this.elevatorService.breakDown();
    return breakDown;
  }

  up() {
    this.floor
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        filter((v) => v < 20),
        map((v) => v + 1)
      )
      .subscribe((v) => this.floor.next(v));
  }

  down() {
    this.floor
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        filter((v) => v > 1),
        map((v) => v - 1)
      )
      .subscribe((v) => this.floor.next(v));
  }
```

My component.html: **The breakDown function is called in the attribute of the disable in the up and down functions**

```
<input type="button" value="Up" (click)="up()" [disabled]="breakDown()" />

<input type="button" value="Down" (click)="down()" [disabled]="breakDown()" />

<div class="elevator">
  <pre class="floor">{{ this.floor | async }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a code demo for you that disables the button after 5 click: [link to the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ghbq83?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Please feel free to adapt the code according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that the disabled property gets triggered only once. Try to bind the [disabled] property to a variable and update it on every click. Then reassign the variable on every click by the breakdown function.
Something like:

Pseudocode:

```
    component.ts:
    upDisabled: boolean;

    up(){
      this.upDisabled = this.breakDown();
    }

    component.html:
    <input type="button" value="Up" (click)="up()" [disabled]="upDisabled" />
```

Of course you can do the other stuff in these functions too.

Edit:
Please look at @Havald's answer on this question:
"@NadavPall Have a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tgphtv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Felevator.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). In your example you return true to disable the buttons if the value is <= 20 so it gets disabled on the first click."

Comment: [I tried to do what you said here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9u7dpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
It did not work for me

Comment: @NadavPall Have a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tgphtv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Felevator.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). In your example you return true to disable the buttons if the value is <= 20 so it gets disabled on the first click.